# What is the benefit the using DesignWare multiplier Library versus custom multiplier?

Tags: verilog

As I know, design ware library has multiplier cell library.but I don't know What is the benefit the using DesignWare multiplier Library versus custom multiplier(like booth algorithm)?

Does anyone know what is different and pros &cons each them?

Answer (score 0):

Generally, using an IP from a vendor/device specific tailored library, is beneficial in a sense that it is implemented with a knowledge of the device's specific special function cells, which might contain a dedicated multiplier, divisor, ROM or whatever is not a standard logic cell. So basically, a complex logic could be implemented without "wasting" standard cells thus preserving them for other stuff.